# ASP.NET MVC: Create ValidationMessageFor Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am generating my form elements by looping over a array. So I have a array = ["name", "age"] and I loop over each item and create a textbox with the appropriate name and related data.

Therefore I creating my form element dynamically such that

```
 <input class="input-validation-error text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="@arr[i] is required" id="@arr[i]" name="@arr[i]" type="text" value="">
 <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="@arr[i]" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Instead of :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.age)
```

However, because of this, the client-side messages are not being generated. It would catch the error in the server-side validation but client-side stop working.

[image]

How can I get the client-side message to work while keeping the ability to create the form dynamically, such that in the blew line of codes the model's property-name can be provided dynamically? Is there a way?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model[@arr[i]])
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[@arr[i]])
```

I know that above code doesn't work but its just to emphasize what I am looking for in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly register validation inline or with JavaScript.

[More jQuery Validate Examples](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) (Below is a brief example)

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
   name: "required"
  }
});
```

Inline ex:

```
<input id="age" name="age" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.MessageViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexStackOverflow900</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var arr in Model.myArray)
            {
                <input class="input-validation-error text-box single-line" data-val="true"
                       data-val-required="@arr is required" id=@arr name=@arr type="text" value="">
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessage(arr);
                i++;
            }

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/Model:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public List<string> myArray = new List<string>();
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string age { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexStackOverflow900(MessageViewModel mvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //you can narrow it down to which field caused the error by inspecting ModelState
            //List<ModelErrorCollection> errors = controller.ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
            //           .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
            //           .ToList();
            ModelState.AddModelError("name", "name is required");
            ModelState.AddModelError("age", "age is required");
        }

        FactorCode(mvm);
        return View(mvm);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexStackOverflow900()
    {
        MessageViewModel mvm = new MessageViewModel();
        FactorCode(mvm);
        return View(mvm);
    }

    public void FactorCode(MessageViewModel mvm)
    {
        mvm.myArray.Add("name");
        mvm.myArray.Add("age");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @kblau I couldn't get server side validation to display when trying to update multiple records in a single form using a foreach (var item in Model.Round.Matches) and replacing your `@Html.ValidationMessage(arg);` with `@Html.ValidationMessage($"Round.Matches[{item.ID}].HomeTeamID")` was just what I needed.